# boost socket_base::bytes_readable returns values when there is nothing to read

Tags: c++, boost

I use boost asio for sync socket server and client.
using socket_base::bytes_readable  to get whether there is any data to read, as suggested [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/socket_base/bytes_readable.html)
worked great for me.

Now I've converted the code to support ssl (using asio::ssl::stream), and the first client read after a the handshake detects 478 bytes to read (should be none)  and gets stuck on WSARecv during  the read attempt (since there is nothing to read).
Switching to async is not an option right now.

Anyone had experience with this problem or any tips how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

asio::ssl::stream does not have that member: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream.html

In fact it has nothing that resembles it. The idea is to have a framing protocol or just use an asynchronous read to detect when data is available.

Interacting with the underlying socket (after handshake) is going to give unspecified results at best, undefined behaviour at worst.